# How to infer a type that depends on the previous type which isn't used in function parameters

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings, type-inference, inferred-type

```
interface User {
    id?: number;
    name?: string;
    email?: string;
    gender?: string;
    status?: string;
}

export const foo = <T extends object, P extends keyof T>(payload: User, pick_keys: P[]) => {
    const result = pick(payload, ['email', 'gender']) as T;

    return pick(result, pick_keys);
};

const {} = foo<User>({ name: 'hh', id: 33 }, ['name', 'id']);
```

why the type `P` isn't being infered from the passed in array of keys ?
and i get a red underline under `foo<User>(...);`

saying that `Expected 2 type arguments, but got 1`

Comment: What is `pick` defined as?

Comment: @caTS 

const pick = <T extends object, K extends keyof T>(payload: T, keys: K[]) => {
    return keys.reduce((prev, key) => {
        return {
            ...prev,
            [key]: payload[key],
        };
    }, {}) as Pick<T, K>;
};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you either have to provide *all* type arguments, or have *all* of them inferred. You cannot provide only some: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242

The only, slightly ugly, solution that I'm aware of is an outer function with one type parameter (which you'll explicitly provide) which returns an inner function with one type parameter (that'll be inferred).

Something like this:

```
function foo_outer<T extends object>() {
  return <P extends keyof T>(payload: User, pick_keys: P[]) => {
    // ...
  };
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
foo_outer<User>()({ name: 'hh', id: 33 }, ['name', 'id'])
            // ^-- note the extra pair of parens
```

Comment: (commonly called currying)

Comment: well thanks your solution gave me an idea to use some proxy or just use the solution as it is